# Pass values from the For loop to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a survey form using ASP.NET MVC architecture.

There is a section where I load the questions for the survey from a model to the view.

The model created as

```
[NotMapped]
    public class QuizForService
    {
        public int MainDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int QuizID { get; set; }
        public string Quiz { get; set; }
        public string AnswerForQuiz { get; set; }
    }
```

So from the controller, I load the Questions to this model

```
List < QuizForService > Questionsto = (from q in db.tbl_QuestionsSub 
                                       where q.ServiceTypeId == ServiceId select new QuizForService 
                                       {
                                        QuizID = q.Id,
                                        Quiz = q.QuestionEng
                                       }).ToList();

return Json(new {
  Success = true,
    questionlist = Questionsto,

}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So in the view, I load the question from `for`loop and the answer list to select users to the related question.

```
for (int i = 0; i < SurveyList.Count; i++) {
  < tr >
    <
    td > @SurveyList[i].Quiz < /td> <
    td > @if(@SurveyList[i].QuizID != 8) {
      @SurveyList[i].AnswerForQuiz < div class = "radio" >
        <
        input label = "Excellent "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Excellent"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Excellent"
      checked >
        <
        input label = "Good "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Good"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Good" >
        <
        input label = "Fair "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Fair"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Fair" >
        <
        input label = "Poor "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Poor"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Poor" >
        <
        /div> } else { <div class="radio"> <
        input label = "Yes "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Yes"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Yes"
      checked >
        <
        input label = "No "
      type = "radio"
      id = "No"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "No" >
        <
        input label = "Maybe "
      type = "radio"
      id = "Maybe"
      name = "@SurveyList[i].QuizID"
      value = "Maybe" >
        <
        /div> } </td >
        <
        /tr>
```

So the view is a single-page application and the process goes like a wizard.

I thought of submitting get those values using javascript and passing it to the controller using Ajax.

I want to know how to get those question IDs with the customer selected answer to the javascript.

Comment: You could add an `onclick` to the inputs and call a js function that way, passing the value to it

Comment: @JamesS I have done it already, but I can't figure out how to get the listed answers to javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-id attribute with ajax.
For example;

```
<input label="Maybe" type="radio" data-id="Maybe" name="@SurveyList[i].QuizID" value="Maybe">
```

and ajax:

```
var id = $(this).data("Maybe");
```

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delayed response from me. I have applied and checked the solution you gave me. Sadly it's not working. Also what I needed was, now these questions loaded to the table from the session list. So I used ``For loop`` to load it to the table and the answers also ( as I shown in my question). So the thing is I still have no idea about how to get as an example question 1 Id and the selected user's answer , and question 2 id and the selected answer like wise to the javascript